# Detect string pattern in dataframe and conditionally fill another in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, stringr

I have a dataframe containing text and numeric references, and a vector of words that may appear in the text. What I want is to check for every instance in which a word from `words_df` appears in `text_df$text`, and record the word from `word_df` and the numeric reference from `text_df$ref` in a new dataframe (`edge_df`).

```
text_df <- data.frame(text = c("John went to the shops", "Sarita hates apples", "Wendy doesn't care about this"),
                      ref = c("13.5", "1.9.9", "20.1"))

words_df <- data.frame(word = c("shops", "John", "apples", "Wendy", "this"))

edge_df <- data.frame(ref = NA, word = NA)
```

The output should look like this:

```
> edge_df
    ref   word
1  13.5  shops
2  13.5   John
3 1.9.9 apples
4  20.1  Wendy
5  20.1   this
```

It isn't very elegant but I thought a for-loop would work, where each word is checked against the text using `stringr::str_detect`, and if the result is `TRUE` it would record the word and ref:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(text_df)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(words_df)) {
    if (str_detect(text_df$text[i], words_df$word[j]) == TRUE) {
      edge_df$ref <- text_df$ref[i]
      edge_df$word <- words_df$word[j]
    }
  }
}
```

This did not work, and nor have several variations on this loop. If possible I would rather not use a loop at all as the dataframes I'm working with have around 1000 rows each and it takes far too long to loop through them. Any fixes to the loop much appreciated, and bonus points/props if you can do it without a loop at all.

Thank you!

Comment: it does not work because with `edge_df$ref <- text_df$ref[i]` (and the next line) you assign a single value to the whole column. You would need to keep a separate counter for the output data frame or use `rbind` to append the newly found matches. Solutions below are much preferable of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `str_extract` and `unnest`.  We extract the words from the 'text' column into a `list` and use `unnest` the expand the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
text_df %>%
   transmute(ref, word = str_extract_all(text, 
                 str_c(words_df$word, collapse="|"))) %>%
   unnest(c(word))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  ref   word  
#  <chr> <chr> 
#1 13.5  John  
#2 13.5  shops 
#3 1.9.9 apples
#4 20.1  Wendy 
#5 20.1  this
```

Comment: Accepting this answer as it worked first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this `tidyverse` approach. The key for your issue: you can format your data to long by separating each word in the sentences and then use `left_join()`. Here the code (I have used the data you provided):

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
text_df <- data.frame(text = c("John went to the shops", "Sarita hates apples", "Wendy doesn't care about this"),
                      ref = c("13.5", "1.9.9", "20.1"),stringsAsFactors = F)

words_df <- data.frame(word = c("shops", "John", "apples", "Wendy", "this"),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Join
words_df %>% left_join(text_df %>% separate_rows(text,sep = ' ') %>%
  rename(word=text))
```

Output:

```
    word   ref
1  shops  13.5
2   John  13.5
3 apples 1.9.9
4  Wendy  20.1
5   this  20.1
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach. It worked on the sample data, but on my real data it returned this error: `no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "factor"`, and returned the same for "character" when I tried to change the class to that. Any idea why?

Comment: @mendy Yes, I know what is happening. Please check that the variables in your dataframe are of class `character` and not `factor`. Let me know if that works :)

Comment: When I convert all the relevant vectors using `as.character()` it returns the same error: `no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "character"`

Comment: Is it possible for you creating a chat and inviting me so that I can help you properly? Here how to do that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow I suspect is the structure of data.

Comment: That would be great, but I need seven more reputation points to have the privilege of creating chat rooms =P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
u <- lapply(text_df$text,function(x) words_df$word[sapply(words_df$word,function(y) grepl(y,x))])
edge_df <- data.frame(ref = rep(text_df$ref,lengths(u)),word = unlist(u))
```

which gives

```
    ref   word
1  13.5  shops
2  13.5   John
3 1.9.9 apples
4  20.1  Wendy
5  20.1   this
```

Answer (score -1):

```
library(data.table)

words_df <- data.frame(word = c("shops", "John", "apples", "Wendy", "this"))

text_df <- data.frame(text = c("John went to the shops", 
                      "Sarita hates apples", "Wendy doesn't care about this"),
                  ref = c("13.5", "1.9.9", "20.1"))

setDT(words_df)
setDT(text_df)
```

First we get our words vector ready.

```
 wordvec <- paste0(words_df[,word],collapse="|")
```

Now all there is to do is to check, for each row all the words in `wordvec`

```
   ## > text_df[,.(word=unlist(regmatches(text,gregexpr(wordvec,text)))),ref] 
##      ref   word
## 1:  13.5   John
## 2:  13.5  shops
## 3: 1.9.9 apples
## 4:  20.1  Wendy
## 5:  20.1   this
```

The functions regmatches,grepexpr will return a list containing all the words that match the pattern `wordvec`.

```
> regmatches("John went to the shops",gregexpr(wordvec,"John went to the shops"))
##[[1]]
##[1] "John"  "shops"
```

Warning, to format the output quickly I'm over-relying the ref variable and consider them to be ids. If it is not the case then it is best to create an id column and use it with in addition to ref. For instance

```
text_df[,id:=1:.N][,.(word=unlist(regmatches(text,
                   gregexpr(wordvec,text)))),.(id,ref)]
```

Comment: I didn't understand the down vote.  I tried to as informative as possible so if you feel I'm missing the point feel free to tell.